# Best of n selected items by comparing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ranking

I have to create a system that compares `N` items.

The system has to tell the user which are his favourite items from a list of `N` items. It has to return a list of stored items ranked from most liked to least by their choice. The background algorithm has to give two items in each round where user votes and the background algorithm compares them and calculates best scored.

What I thought first was classic: `Combination without repetition`:

Example: 
There are ten animals `(n = 10)`

```
{"Dog", "Cat", "Squirrel", "Chimpanzee", "Ox", "Lion", "Panda", "Walrus", "Otter", "Elephant"}
```

If I use Combination without repetition according to formula `n!/k!*(n-k)!` there were be 45 comparisons

```
{"Dog", "Cat"},
{"Dog", "Squirrel"},
{"Dog", "Chimpanzee"}
...
{"Cat", "Cat"},
{"Cat", "Chimpanzee"},
{"Cat", "Ox"}
...
```

If the user chooses Dog 5 times Dog gets 5 points, any others that were chosen versus Dog get 1 point, and next is Cat, then Squirrel and etc... 
And the list at the end will look smth like this:

```
"Dog" : 8,
"Cat" : 6,
"Squirrel" : 3
...
```

But I find this logic very ineffective because users have to choose `45` times, plus `N` can be above `10` so the number will increase dramatically and the system will lose sense.

Do you know some efficient algorithms for comparing items, with sorted ranked list at the end as an outcome?

Comment: So, just to check if I understood correctly: The user is presented with two randomly chosen, however different elements from a list of `N` elements. The user then decides whether he likes element 1 more than element 2 or the other way around. If element 1 was chosen over element 2, element 1 receives 5 points, element 2 only 1? After each possible pair in the list has been played, you want to return the list sorted by points? Or do you want to optimize, how many comparisons have been played? Also, if you want the second way, are there any limitations in terms of space complexity?

Comment: Each one receives one point when chosen over another, with that one I wanted to say if you choose a dog as first element than dog has to be compared with 9 others, if in scenario dog is chosen five times (over five other animals) than dog gets 5 points. In the next iteration, we get the second element so e.g. cat is compared with 8 others cuz we have the result from the dog/cat comparison can be either 0 or 1 point for the cat. etc..

Comment: I want to optimize the number of comparisons more particular to not be needed to compare all with all, don't know is there is any logical solution to get that but for bigger N numbers this logic is meaningless as user experience

Comment: No there are no limitations for space

Comment: The second solution I thought was limitng to the first best 5 items, it may optimize a little but still not the best solution @CodingTil

Answer (score 0):

So you want to sort items by comparing them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort

You'll have to do `O(N log(N))` comparisons.